# Save response from async request to value (node js)

Tags: javascript

```
async function checkStatus() {
  const data = await fetch();

  return data.json();
}

const result = checkStatus() // Promise
```

How can I make something like `await` for response from `checkStatus()` outside of the `function`. As I understand it isn't possible to make:

```
const result = await checkStatus()
```

But how can I make something similar ?

Comment: "*As I understand it isn't possible to make*" - no, why would that be impossible? It's actually just the solution.

Comment: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function - I get when I do this

Answer (score 1):

There are some environments that support "top-level await" so `const result = await checkStatus()` would actually work.

In environments that don't support top-level await, you can wrap your whole `const result = await checkStatus()` inside an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) as follows (note the function is an `async` one).

```js
async function checkStatus() {
  const data = await fetch();

  return data.json();
}

(async () => {
  const result = await checkStatus();
})();
```

Alternatively you can just use the Promise API:

```js
checkStatus().then(result => {
  // do stuff with result
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code inside an async function:

```js
(async () => {
  const result = await checkStatus();
  // ...
})();
```

Or use `.then()`:

```js
checkStatus().then(result => {
  // ...
});
```